# Import multi EXCEL files with relationship between them( Vlookup ) into MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, vlookup

I have multiple Excel files that have relation between them. I want to use their data and develop a Web Application. First of all I need to import them into SQL server.( I think SQL Server is more compatible with Excel files ) But some of them have lots of records and and also relationship.(vlookup) How can I import them with their relations into SQL Server? Is there any way?

Note that I use SQL Server 2016, and excel file format is 2007-2010, But I open the excel file in Microsoft Office Excel 2016 as well.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't execute the files or their macros. Import means simply import the data, eg using SSIS or the `Import Data` task in SSMS which effectively generates an SSIS package

Comment: Copy / Paste.Special Values, then treat as data...

Comment: BTW Excel sheets have no relations. VLOOKUP is just a function. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files. You don't need Excel itself to read it. You can read it directly, throug the OpenXML SDK or use a library like Epplus. In a web application you can read the uploaded files in your code, retrieve the data and insert it into a database using eg EF, ADO.NET or SqlBulkCopy

Comment: @SolarMike how do you do that in a web application? Why would you do that in SSMS when Import is already available?

Comment: SQL Server isn't more compatible with any data file. Its `Import Data` wizard and the SSIS packages it generates can read from any available source, from CSV files to other databases to Hadoop.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos probably because the source is the excel files... as per the OP's post, first line...

Comment: @SloarMike :  This web app is based on the good materials and prices.
It first goal is to calculate the price of the product.
each table and excel file has some fields with their prices.
I want to make this as a web app.
Count of records are growing up and excel become unusable.

Comment: @SolarMike that doesn't mean the *application* is open, or that it can be opened at all on the web server. Even on the desktop why open Excel just to paste the data into SSMS when you can import them faster than you can open Excel itself? Copy/paste doesn't give you any control of the types and forces conversions to text which can cause serious problems with dates and numbers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Copy paste special values does not always force text...

Comment: @alirezaazadi then when you tag excel, you should expect comments / answers relevant to excel, if you don't want excel don't use the tag...

Comment: @SolarMike it's never, ever used for importing data. `not always` is unacceptable in any kind of production environment and all but the most simplistic development and testing environments. *Especially* when different decimal points and date formats are involved.

Comment: So you guys telling me there is no way to import excel file with vlookup relations into sql server, right?
And is there any way to create and generate a diagram from Excel file with vlookup relations?
I googled and found power pivot, But seems does not work for Vlookup relationship.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used to use SAS to analyse data (one data file of 10megs to produce 180,000 result files to be charted), so avoided any excel issues...

Comment: @alirezaazadi no, I'm saying that there are no relations to begin with. VLOOKUP is just a function, it doesn't specify any kind of relation. *Real* relations exist in the Power pivot data model. You can convert that model to an SSAS Tabular cube directly using the [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017). SSAS Tabular uses the same engine as PowerPivot.

Comment: @SolarMike that's because SAS is the *processing* software. Not the ETL product. 180K rows is a very small amount of data anyway - even Excel can store 1M rows and handle far more data through PowerPivot, as much as can fit in memory. If the source file locale matches your locale, you wouldn't have problems. Try importing dates from French, German and Polish sources though, in an ETL job every 15 minutes. Even small data marts have dozens of millions of rows and use many GBs of storage

Comment: @SolarMike SAS has conversion problems too, if the wrong settings are used to load the data. SAS, R etc are good tools to *analyze* sample data and discover patterns, distributions, values that are then used to create appropriate ETL scripts or jobs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the solution is to know what your data is and make sure you deal with it correctly... ie test and test again before you hit "go"... Oh and the 180,000 result files are not 1 row each...

Comment: @SolarMike in the real world your data will change a *lot* after you hit `Go`, especially when it's not *your* data - it comes from other systems, other companies, or in this case, from a user uploading a file that could contain anything. In ETL jobs the data gets tested automatically in every run to detect anomalies

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos which "real world" ?? - the data we dealt with was sent to us each month by the company data processing unit... And they had their own quality controls...

Comment: So final solution is to convert this vlookup functions into power pivot and then import them into sql server?
In this way the relations exist in the sql server?
Or better way is to analysis data and import each table separately with their relations? 
 Which way you finally suggest?